# Why does Symfony2 ACL go by username instead of ID?

Tags: symfony, acl

I just started using Symfony's ACL system and was wondering why `UserSecurityIdentity` uses the `username` instead of the `id` of a User object to determine it's identity?

```
$user = new User();
$user->setId(new \MongoId());
$user->setUsername("frodo");
$dm->persist($user);

$uid = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user); // uses "frodo"
```

Our system allows users to alter their username, so using something more permanent (like the ID) to determine a user's identity seems more appropriate to me. Why was the ACL system implemented to use the username and not the ID? Any security considerations here?

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been discussed here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5787

And has been solved in this commit:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8d39213f4cca19466f84a5656a199eee98602ab1

So, now, whenever a user alter it's username, you can update its security indentity. I use a listener to do this:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
        /** Update user security identity in case nick is changed * */
        if ($entity instanceof \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User && $eventArgs->hasChangedField('username')) {
            $aclProvider = $this->container->get('security.acl.provider');
            $securityId = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($entity);
            $aclProvider->updateUserSecurityIdentity($securityId, $eventArgs->getOldValue('username'));
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is implementation of `fromAccount()` method from `Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\UserSecurityIdentity` class:

```
public static function fromAccount(UserInterface $user)
{
    return new self($user->getUsername(), ClassUtils::getRealClass($user));
}
```

I think it is answer on your question.

Comment: I've seen the implementation. The question was WHY did they do it that way and not use ID instead. Is there any security implication to using ID rather than username. They've also made that class `final` so it can't even be overridden to do a custom implementation.

Comment: @anushr Maybe Fabien Potencier can ask on the question WHY? ;)
And btw i think that using non unic username - not good practice.